# proxyBeanMthods annotation error when running springboot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am trying to run my first springboot application but facing some issues.

In my application file, this is my code

```
package com.clog.ServiceMgmt;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("models")
@ComponentScan({"com.clog.ServiceMgmt","controllers", "models", "repositories"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"repositories"})
public class ServiceMgmtApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceMgmtApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

but when i run my application, i get the following error. confused as to why i should get this error and how to solve it.

> org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationConfigurationException:
>   Attribute 'proxyBeanMethods' in annotation
>   [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication] is
>   declared as an @AliasFor nonexistent attribute 'proxyBeanMethods' in
>   annotation [org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration].;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration.proxyBeanMethods()

This is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.clog</groupId>
    <artifactId>ServiceMgmt</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>ServiceMgmt</name>
    <description>Service Mgmt</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a `@Configuration` annotated class?

Comment: @MadhuBhat no i dont. Am i supposed to have one and if yes, where do i put that?

Comment: Can you tell us which dependencies (+ versions) you use? It sounds like you're trying to use 2.2.0.M1 with an older version of Spring.

Comment: spring-boot-2.2.0 snapshot

Comment: @g00glen00b added my pom.xml file

Comment: @KingsleySimon Any reason why you're using a snapshot version of Spring boot, rather than a stable release?

Comment: @g00glen00b followed a tutorial online.

Comment: @KingsleySimon by any chance were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @Akki i did but forgot how. What current issues are you facing? Maybe i can help

Comment: @KingsleySimon I was getting the same error which you posted in your question, I don't face that issue anymore, but I don't remember now how I resolved it :D

Answer (score 12):

from [spring-projects-github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18190)

" proxyBeanMethods is new in 5.2 and I can see 5.1.2.RELEASE in some elements of the stack."

do a dependency:tree and double check that spring match >= 5.2, I had a similar issue and one library brought 5.1 overriding v5.2 from springboot

Answer (score 2):

Had same problem few days ago. Try to change spring-boot-starter-parent version to 2.1.3.RELEASE, thats resolved my problem.

Comment: it will remove the error but might get new errors if some things are used that are not present in version 2.1.3

Answer (score 1):

use this in your main springboot application class :@SpringBootApplication(proxyBeanMethods = false)

this will work .

Comment: didn't work for me. What is the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error happen in a Spring Boot project where I added a custom dependency that made use of Spring (not Spring Boot). The issue in my custom dependency was that it had the following plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>

            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>

            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer
implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Implementation-Title>${project.name}</Implementation-Title>
                            <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
                            <Implementation-Vendor>Vendor Name, ${timestamp}</Implementation-Vendor>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>

                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Once I removed the shade plugin from my custom dependency, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the following dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And the code was up like magic