# Spring Boot Application run failed : how to fix an AnnotationConfigurationException (nonexistent attribute)

Tags: java, spring, git, spring-boot, annotations

My project lost after the change of a branch in Git the build path references for some imported packages - I had to use the "Fix project" function of Eclipse and manually reenrich thepom.xml. Since then none of my branches, nor the master of my project compile. Another Spring boot application in the same workspace still compiles normally. MySprinApplication branches and master, also after restarting Eclipse, Maven Clean + Install, all have and keep the same error :

Here the Console message. Do you have any idea what I could try? Thank you very much in advance. Maven claims that the pom.xml does not exist,...

:: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.1.RELEASE)

```
org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationConfigurationException: Attribute 'proxyBeanMethods' in annotation [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication] is declared as an @AliasFor nonexistent attribute 'proxyBeanMethods' in annotation [org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration].
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMapping.resolveAliasTarget(AnnotationTypeMapping.java:162) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMapping.resolveAliasTarget(AnnotationTypeMapping.java:133) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMapping.resolveAliasedForTargets(AnnotationTypeMapping.java:125) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMapping.<init>(AnnotationTypeMapping.java:102) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.addIfPossible(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:116) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.addAllMappings(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:75) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.<init>(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:68) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.<init>(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:46) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings$Cache.createMappings(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:253) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings$Cache.get(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:249) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.forAnnotationType(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:206) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.forAnnotationType(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:188) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.forAnnotationType(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:175) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotations$IsPresent.doWithAnnotations(TypeMappedAnnotations.java:330) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotations$IsPresent.doWithAnnotations(TypeMappedAnnotations.java:279) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.processClassHierarchy(AnnotationsScanner.java:211) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.processClassHierarchy(AnnotationsScanner.java:194) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.processClass(AnnotationsScanner.java:128) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.process(AnnotationsScanner.java:107) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.scan(AnnotationsScanner.java:97) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.scan(AnnotationsScanner.java:78) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotations.scan(TypeMappedAnnotations.java:242) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotations.isPresent(TypeMappedAnnotations.java:98) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.isComponent(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:279) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:156) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:136) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:128) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.load(SpringApplication.java:691) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:392) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at fr.minint.signmi.trust.ServicesDeConfianceApplication.main(ServicesDeConfianceApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
```

**pom.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>exemple.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyApplication</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2</version>
    <name>ServiceApplication</name>
    <description>Services</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spécifique à Thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Webjars, permettant l'inclusion de bibliothèques type Bootstrap ou 
            JQuery -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Pour les tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Bibliothèques diverses -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-ext-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.62</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Pour consommer le service WSDL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Pour se connecter au stockage objet du Cloud PI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javaswift</groupId>
            <artifactId>joss</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdf-js</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.266</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <rules>
                        <dependencyConvergence />
                    </rules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**WebMVCConfig.java**

```
package exemple.com.serviceApplication.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.ISpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode;

@Configuration
public class WebMVCConfig
    implements WebMvcConfigurer, ApplicationContextAware {

  private static final String UTF8 = "UTF-8";

  @Autowired
  private ISpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
  }

  @Bean
  public ThymeleafViewResolver jnlpThymeleafViewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(this.templateEngine);
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding(UTF8);
    resolver.setContentType("application/x-java-jnlp-file");
    resolver.setViewNames(new String[] {"*.jnlp"});
    resolver.setCache(false);
    return resolver;
  }

  @Bean
  public SpringResourceTemplateResolver jnlpTemplateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
    resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/jnlp/");
    resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.XML);
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding(UTF8);
    resolver.setCheckExistence(true);
    resolver.setCacheable(false);
    return resolver;
  }

}
```

Comment: Please show your pom.xml

Comment: Also the class with the @Configuration annotation could be useful.

Comment: Generally these kind of errors stem from the mixture of jars/modules from different version of Spring / Spring Boot.

Comment: Ok, I included the pom.xml and a @Configuration annotation class.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this question:
[proxyBeanMthods annotation error when running springboot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55293320/proxybeanmthods-annotation-error-when-running-springboot-application)

from spring-projects-github -> proxyBeanMethods is new in 5.2

Verify that all Spring dependencies are using the newest versions, and that any conflicts are also resolving correctly to the same Spring boot versions.